# C1 FlexChart Uncaught ReferenceError: c1 is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I'm new using C1 or ComponentOne and I'm having problem for rendering FlexChart. It always caught this error.
[image]
[image]
I already have the reference in my controller and on the view itself and nothing seems to work. I decided to ask this question here because it's much more quick to have response here than on their support I'm using trial version of their component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try this, add this in your view, this is work for me

```
@Html.C1().Resources("default")
```

Comment: What version of ComponentOne you use? If newer version, maybe need change to @Html.C1().Resource.Basic(), something like this, please refer to autoprompting.